# Counter Countup implemented with moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to implement a counter starts at 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss) and shows it every second in a span. I am not getting to start with hour = 00.  It shows me 10:00:00 at the beginning.

The code is following:

```js
var startTimestamp;
function startTimer()
{
    var startTimestamp = moment().startOf("day");
    setInterval(function() {
        startTimestamp++;
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 
            moment.unix(startTimestamp).format('hh:mm:ss');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe a locale issue? Output the current time from moment and see if it includes a 'z' at the end, which would indicate a UTC time.

Comment: The output doesn't include any 'z' at the end...

Comment: Is it still outputting 10 now? Or has it changed? If it has moved on it would indicate that it is a locale issue and you're not getting the right time zone back from moment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `startTimestamp` is a moment object you can modify its value using [`add()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) instead of using `startTimestamp++`. Note that [`add()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/):

> Mutates the original moment by adding time.

Then there is no reason to use [`moment.unix()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/), you can simply use [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) on `startTimestamp`.

Finally, as [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs states, lowercase `hh` stands for `01 02 ... 11 12` hours while uppercase `HH` stands for `00 01 ... 22 23`, so I think you have to use the latter.

Here a live sample:

```js
function startTimer()
{
    var startTimestamp = moment().startOf("day");
    setInterval(function() {
        startTimestamp.add(1, 'second');
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 
            startTimestamp.format('HH:mm:ss');
    }, 1000);
}

startTimer();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="timer"></div>
```